# Devise and OmniAuth for api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I have a rails website in which I am using `devise` and `OmniAuth` for authentication (email + social authentication). Now I want to implement an api that will serve as a backend for my android app. I was wondering how can I  extend my existing authentication system so that I can provide the same authentication functionality of email and social login to my android users?  Also, a person should be able to login using same credentials on web and android app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add api token field in your user table.

Everytime when a android user request for login, after successfully match email and paasword an API token will create with expiration time. Then each time API token must be send with android request.

Request will be completed if the API token is valid.

To differentiate your request you can use namespace in your route like /api/v1/login

Comment: I have added this auth_token field and I am using the gem simple_auth_token to implement this. I followed this blog for implementation  http://provoost.tumblr.com/post/80873086965/json-api-authentication-using-devise-tokens . But by doing this the authentication for api works fine but website authentication ceases to work .

Comment: As per your suggestion I used different namespace for api the code that I implemented is available here: https://github.com/lovishchoudhary/devisetest
Using this approach my website authentication is working fine but for api only the sign_up function from curl is working fine but the sign_in function is giving error. I have also asked the same question with full details here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050423/common-devise-login-for-web-and-api  . Please take a look at the code and let me know what error I am making